# Up and down a docker container while app is running in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a container that i just want it to come up a certain time of the day, after that I want it to stop (I'm using rails)

Can i create a control variable for him?

Ex:

At 00 am until 01 am he's running, after that the variable turning into false and just that container stop.

The docker-compose that I using for it:

```
  sentiment-analyzer:
    build: ./sentiment-analyzer
    container_name: sentiment-analyzer
    ports:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./sentiment-analyzer-mock:/app
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

I'm using that docker for text analyze with BERT in python. So, in that time i want send texts and recive the result.
The rest of the time it would only consume memory if it kept running, so I want it to only go up at that time...

Comment: Does `docker compose up sentiment-analyzer` not work for you? Could you update your question on reasons why you can't/dont want to use it?

Comment: I haver four others dockers, and ALL run together. And The server is stay up all time.

Comment: ok, but you can do `docker up service1 service2 service3` (specify exactly what should run immediately and stay up). Another option would be to extract `sentiment-analyzer` to a separate docker-compose file (you'd need to expose the other services' ports if the `sentiment-analyzer` uses it, e.g. DB).